# Dplyr: return flow of values min, max in each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use Dplyr to get following data organized:

```
id <- c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3")
type <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A")
date_collected <- as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-05"))
df <- data.frame(id, type, date_collected)
```

Data Frame:

```
id  type    date_collected
1   A       2018-01-01
2   A       2018-01-01
3   B       2018-01-01
1   A       2018-01-02
2   B       2018-01-02
3   B       2018-01-02
1   B       2018-01-03
2   B       2018-01-03
3   A       2018-01-03
1   B       2018-01-04
2   B       2018-01-04
3   A       2018-01-04
1   A       2018-01-05
2   B       2018-01-05
3   A       2018-01-05
```

I'm trying to get the following output:

```
id  type    min_date    max_date
1   A       2018-01-01  2018-01-02
1   B       2018-01-03  2018-01-04
1   A       2018-01-05  2018-01-05
2   A       2018-01-01  2018-01-01
2   B       2018-01-02  2018-01-05
3   B       2018-01-01  2018-01-02
3   A       2018-01-03  2018-01-05
```

This is the Dplyr code that I tried to use, without success:

```
df %>% group_by(id, type) %>% summarise(min_date = min(date_collected), max_date = max(date_collected), n = n())
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want 2 rows for `id = 1` and `type = A`?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, but I'm not getting the 3rd row (where `id = 1` and `type = A` the 2nd time.

Comment: Is the problem an error message or is the output not giving you what you want?  If you are getting an error message, what is the message?  If the output isn't what you want, you need to explain exactly what you do want, and how it's different from what you are currently getting.

Comment: What I want is to see how the `id` changed the `type` over time (`min_date` and `max_date`). That's because I want three rows for `id = 1`, so I can capture the change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close to solution. You need to convert your `date_collected` column to `Date` type before applying `min/max`. One option using `lubridate` along with `dplyr` is:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)


df %>% mutate(date_collected = ymd(date_collected), type = as.character(type)) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id, type, chng_over = cumsum(type != lag(type, default = " "))) %>%
  summarise(min_date = min(date_collected), max_date = max(date_collected)) %>%
  arrange(chng_over) %>% select(-chng_over)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups: id, type [6]
# id    type  min_date   max_date  
# <chr> <chr> <date>     <date>    
# 1 1     A     2018-01-01 2018-01-02
# 2 1     B     2018-01-03 2018-01-04
# 3 1     A     2018-01-05 2018-01-05
# 4 2     A     2018-01-01 2018-01-01
# 5 2     B     2018-01-02 2018-01-05
# 6 3     B     2018-01-01 2018-01-02
# 7 3     A     2018-01-03 2018-01-05
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately one line from my expected output is missing: `1 | A | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-05`. This would be the third line from my post. What I want is to see how the `id` changed the `type` over time (`min_date` and `max_date`). That's because I want three rows for `id = 1`, so I can capture the change over time. Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: @User Understood the logic now. It was not clear for me if `1 | A | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-05` row was needed. Have a look at updated answer.

Comment: @User Fantastic. We can clear some of the comments which may not help future users.